# Nested nets of closed bounded star-shaped sets in a semi-reflexive space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Among Hausdorff locally convex spaces, semi-reflexivity is characterized by the weak topology having the Heine-Borel property. It follows that, in a semi-reflexive space, every nested net of closed bounded nonempty convex sets has nonempty intersection.

Stated in terms of sequence, this is actually a characterization of reflexivity in the normed case, by a theorem of Smulian. Moreover, Klee extended the result from nonempty convex sets to star-shaped sets. My two questions are whether those results extend to Hausdorff locally convex spaces:

1. If a Hausdorff locally convex space satisfies that every nested net of closed bounded nonempty convex sets has nonempty intersection, is it semi-reflexive?
2. If a Hausdorff locally convex space satisfies the hypothesis of 1, does it actually satisfy that every nested net of closed bounded star-shaped sets has nonempty intersection?

For references, see:

- *Bernardes, Nilson C. jun.*, [**On nested sequences of convex sets in Banach spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2011.12.002), J. Math. Anal. Appl. 389, No. 1, 558-561 (2012). [ZBL1241.46007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1241.46007).

Comment: Semi-reflexivity is equivalent to the **weak** compactness of closed bounded subsets.

Comment: Indeed... Corrected, thanks.